# Boeing Dreamliner MCAS

Tags: aircraft-design, mcas

If it was not known that Boeing had new software in the Boeing 737 Max, do we know whether this same software is not in the 787-9?

Comment: Lack of initial research before asking question.

Comment: Stop..........just, stop.  I’m not feeding this.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It’s not their power, it’s their geometry that required MCAS...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast That's a reason to downvote, not close.

Comment: @CptReynolds Fair point

Comment: @DavidRicherby: a reason to close however would be: [Do Max 8 and 787 use the same computer override system that led to the Lion Air crash?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/61055/14897)

Answer (score 7):

**No**, we don’t know for sure. We do know, however, that **it wouldn’t make any sense to install it**.

It’s a bit like asking „are we sure the electric VW Golf doesn’t run the Diesel cheating software?“ - We don’t know, as the VW electric motor control code is not public (as far as I know), but it wouldn’t make much sense to fit it, right?